# How to adjust numeric fields in a text file

Tags: text-processing

Suppose I have the following `<Tab>` separated text file:

```
file name    size      owner    
file1.txt    12.345    root
file2.txt    0.172222  user1
file3.txt    2.46e2    user2
file4.txt    12345     root
file5.txt    21        user3
file6.txt    246.0     user1
file name    owner     last modified    last accessed
text4.txt    root      12.73            13.53
text5.txt    user3     15.3333          34
file1.txt    root      23               31.0032
```

This file consists of several "tables", each of which starts with a header line and then contains some data lines.
Some columns are numeric, but each table can have different number, as well as different types of columns. The types of columns are not known in advance and they can not be determined according to the table header.

The numeric values in the table use various formats - there might be integers, as well as floating point decimal numbers or also numbers in scientific notation.

My question is how to convert all the numeric fields in this table into the same format. For example, I might want to have every numeric field formatted with a `"%.2f"` printf format specifier. Naturally, the other, non-numeric fields must remain unchanged.

Also, I would like to be able to arbitrarily adjust (e.g. add 42 and then multiply by 7) every numeric field contained in this file.

The solution I am looking for should be field-based.
It should scan the entire file and for each field it should determine whether it is numeric or not. If it is numeric, it should print its adjusted and formatted value. Otherwise, it should just print the original.

I know that something like that can be done with `awk`. But if I remember correctly, `awk` uses `double` for internal representation of numbers and therefore it might have problems with precision and larger values. So, ideally, I would like to use something else, something which should correctly handle at least 64 bit integers.

Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Comment: `gawk` uses [double precision floating point numbers](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Basic-Data-Typing.html)

Comment: From Wikipedia: Double-precision floating-point is an IEEE 754 standard for encoding binary or decimal floating-point numbers in 64 bits (8 bytes).

Besides, `awk` uses `double` as well. And as far as I know, it is not possible to store 64 bit integers in a 64 bit floating point format without the loss of precision. Granted, `double` **can** handle 32 bit integers correctly, but that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: I'm almost sure there are 64bit versions of gawk available. What you describe in your comment sounds like the 32bit version, but I don't have time to research now. Good luck.

Comment: I am not sure we understand each other. I admit that [?]awk uses 64 bit, double precision floating point numbers, also-called `double`, for internal storage of numeric values. But 64 bit `double` is not enough to store all the possible values of 64 bit integer.

Comment: You need to find *all* the possible formats for what you want to be expressed as a number, and possible which of them need to be interpreted as integers. You could then parse each field - maybe using a regex to find out if it is an integer, float, or something else. If you did it in Python then Python has bigints and you can use the decimal module if you need to preserve certain accuracy in floating point calcs. But remember, if you can't say what constitutes numbers with some accuracy up-front then you are likely to miss some numbers in any code you generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perl has a module called `Scalar::Util` (included with perl since v5.8) which has a useful function called `looks_like_number()`, which can be used to detect whether a field is a number or not.

`looks_like_number` is not perfect, but is pretty good.

The bare outline of a simple perl program to do what you want might look something like this:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl

use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);

while(<>) {
  chomp;
  my @fields=split("\t");
  foreach my $f (0..scalar @fields-1) {
    if (looks_like_number($fields[$f])) {
      $fields[$f] += 42;
      $fields[$f] *= 7;
      $fields[$f] = sprintf("%.2f",$fields[$f]);
    }
  }
  print join("\t",@fields),"\n";
}
```

If given your sample data above as input, it prints this:

```perl
file name   size    owner    
file1.txt   380.41  root
file2.txt   295.21  user1
file3.txt   2016.00 user2
file4.txt   86709.00    root
file5.txt   441.00  user3
file6.txt   2016.00 user1
file name   owner   last modified   last accessed
text4.txt   root    383.11  388.71
text5.txt   user3   401.33  532.00
file1.txt   root    455.00  511.02
```

Here's another version of the script that uses Math::BigFloat for all calculations, rounding decimals to 2 digits.

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl

use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);
use Math::BigFloat;

while(<>) {
  chomp;
  my @fields=split("\t");
  foreach my $f (0..scalar @fields-1) {
    if (looks_like_number($fields[$f])) {
      my $BF = Math::BigFloat->new($fields[$f]);
      $BF->badd(42);
      $BF->bmul(7);
      $BF->ffround(-2);

      $fields[$f] = $BF->bstr();
    }
  }
  print join("\t",@fields),"\n";
}
```

example input:

```perl
file name   owner   last modified   last accessed
text4.txt   root    12.73   13.53
text5.txt   user3   15.3333 34
file6.txt   root    903709792518875002.42857142857142857142 903709792518875002
file7.txt   root    6659166111488656281486807152009765625   539422123247359763587428687890625
```

output:

```perl
file name   owner   last modified   last accessed
text4.txt   root    383.11  388.71
text5.txt   user3   401.33  532.00
file6.txt   root    6325968547632125311.00  6325968547632125308.00
file7.txt   root    46614162780420593970407650064068359669.00   3775954862731518345112000815234669.00
```

Comment: Very simple and quite elegant solution, thank you! But perl also has issues with 64 bit integers. For example, if a field contains `6325968547632125311`, it is formatted as `6325968547632125952.00`, which is obviously not the same number. Nevertheless, your answer is usable on smaller numbers, so I vote it up!

Comment: Use Math::BigInt to get higher precision.

Comment: It sounds reasonable. But could you please provide an example of how can it be used in the code above? I am mostly concerned about properly formatting the output, since simply calling `printf("%.2f", ...)` on `Math::BigInt` seems to introduce the same loss of precision as before.

Comment: as you said yourself, 64-bit double is not enough to store all possible 64 bit integers.  This is why perl has a Math::BigInt module. A float is not an int, and converting between them (as is done by printf %.2f) will inevitably cause loss of precision.  To handle both bigints and floats reliably you'll have to detect the type of number inside the main loop and take appropriate action. if bigint do bigint calcs and cvt to string to store back in @fields[$f] else do float calcs and use printf as in my example code.

Comment: or use Math::BigFloat for all numbers.  I've added another version which does that.

Comment: Your second solution with `Math::BigFloat` seems to be working properly. Accepted as an answer!